# javascript Promises/A+ chain cycle typeError means infinite loop to overflow the stack or does it mean a forever 'pending' promise that stops?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, circular-reference

Here is my customized promise implementation, please bear with my rough coding. the question is about this check below to make sure promise does not have circular reference. Promises/A+ says it will cause infinite loop, but when I ran the test, it will stop immediately.

```
if (bridgepromise === x) {
        return reject(new TypeError('Circular reference/Chaining cycle detected for promise #<Promise>'));
    }
```

so my test was

```
let p = new customizedPromise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(1)
})

let testPromise = p.then(value => { return testPromise })

testPromise.then(data => console.log(data))
```

It got me thinking what does promises/A+ means by saying infinite loop, does it mean it will cause the resolvePromise function run over and over again? or does it mean it never resolves or rejects?
or my implementation of promises still have bugs? or my test is just inadequate? very confused.

As I console.log in the resolvePromise function, it's not reaching the callback in then, and it is not reaching the resolvePromise(bridgePromise, y, resolve, reject) under.

```
  const PENDING = "pending";
const FULFILLED = "fulfilled";
const REJECTED = "rejected";

function customizedPromise(cb) {
    let self = this
    self.value = null;
    self.error = null;
    self.status = PENDING;
    self.onFulfilledCallBack = [];
    self.onRejectedCallBack = [];

    function resolve(value) {
        // be careful about setTimeout's this
        
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (self.status === PENDING){
                //actually here setting status is for later use
                self.status = FULFILLED;
                self.value = value;
                self.onFulfilledCallBack.forEach(cb => cb(value))}
            })
    }

    function reject(error) {
        
            setTimeout(() => {
                //actually here setting status is for later use
                if (self.status === PENDING){
                self.status = REJECTED;
                self.error = error;
                self.onRejectedCallBack.forEach(cb => cb(error))}
            })
    }

    cb(resolve, reject)
}

// be careful about arrow function's this if you define then function as an arrow function
// it will point to the window
customizedPromise.prototype.then = function (onFulfilled, onRejected) {

    let self = this;
    let bridgePromise;

    onFulfilled = typeof onFulfilled === "function" ? onFulfilled : value => value;
    onRejected = typeof onRejected === "function" ? onRejected : error => { throw error };

    if (self.status === FULFILLED) {
        return bridgePromise = new customizedPromise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                try {
                    let x = onFulfilled(self.value);
                    resolvePromise(bridgePromise, x, resolve, reject);
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            });
        })
    }
    if (self.status === REJECTED) {
        return bridgePromise = new customizedPromise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                try {
                    let x = onRejected(self.error);
                    resolvePromise(bridgePromise, x, resolve, reject);
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    if (self.status === PENDING) {
        return bridgePromise = new customizedPromise((resolve, reject) => {
            self.onFulfilledCallBack.push((value) => {
                try {
              
                    let x = onFulfilled(value);
                    resolvePromise(bridgePromise, x, resolve, reject);
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            });
            self.onRejectedCallBack.push((error) => {
                try {
                    let x = onRejected(error);
                    resolvePromise(bridgePromise, x, resolve, reject);
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}


function resolvePromise(bridgePromise, x, resolve, reject) {

    let called = false;

/* this if condition is not here when I run test */
    **if (bridgePromise === x) {
        return reject(new TypeError('Circular reference/Chaining cycle detected for promise #<Promise>'));
    }**

    if (x != null && ((typeof x === 'object') || (typeof x === 'function'))) {
        try {
            let then = x.then;
            if (typeof then === 'function') {
                then.call(x, y => {
                    console.log("it is not reaching here, hence no reference cycle")
                    if (called) return;
                    called = true;
                    resolvePromise(bridgePromise, y, resolve, reject);
                }, error => {
                    if (called) return;
                    called = true;
                    reject(error);
                })
            } else {
                resolve(x);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            if (called) return;
            called = true;
            reject(e);
        }
    }
    else {
        resolve(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: `let testPromise = p.then(value => { return testPromise })` why do you return something that has just been declared in the same sentence? What is the point of this `then`?

Comment: [promises/A+ doc](https://promisesaplus.com/#notes) @Ngoc I was trying to replicate the case that causing chaining cycle. If a promise is resolved with a thenable that participates in a circular thenable chain, such that the recursive nature of [[Resolve]](promise, thenable) eventually causes [[Resolve]](promise, thenable) to be called again, following the above algorithm will lead to infinite recursion. Implementations are encouraged, but not required, to detect such recursion and reject promise with an informative TypeError as the reason.

Comment: If it never reaches the callback in `then`, there is definitely a bug in your implementation of this promise. I've been staring at it for the last 15 minutes, but it's not really jumping out at me.

Maybe you need some simpler test cases to figure out where your bug is? Here's my implementation and the algorithm seems simpler: https://github.com/evert/promise-demo/blob/master/src/my-promise.js

Comment: @Evert I've tested multiple cases. just this one is annoying, you can just add the if condition and there will be no problems, but not knowing the true origin of the problem upsets me. I've tried your implementation, it seems to have the same problem, there is no recursion calling happening